# Bad position using bootstrap grid

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help with the next thing:

[image: image 1]

Those would be:

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=x" style="margin:5px 5px;">User Simple1<br></a>
                        </div><div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=x" style="margin:5px 5px;">User Advanced2<br>Title</a>
                        </div><div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=x" style="margin:5px 5px;">User Simple3<br></a>
                        </div><div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=x" style="margin:5px 5px;">User Advanced4<br>Title 4</a>
                        </div><div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=x" style="margin:5px 5px;">User Advanced5<br>Title 5</a>
                        </div></div>
```

The size of the div is different each time because the div might have a 'title' right after `<br>` .

So I need help in getting the order I 'painted' in the image above. Any ideas?

Thank you!

The CSS for the buttons:

```
color: #3F484D;
background: linear-gradient(to left, #d9534f .0em, transparent 1.0em) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to left, white,white) no-repeat, linear-gradient(#D4D3D3, #D4D3D3);
display: flex;
border-radius: 5px;
line-height: 2em;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 1px 1px;
padding-left: 1px;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
text-indent: 0.7em each-line;
text-align: center;
min-width: 135px;
font-size: 12px;
background-clip: border-box,content-box, border-box;
```

}

EDIT: Thanks for the flex idea.

The problem in using class row for each 3 divs is next:
I have something like this:

```
  print '<div class="row">';
    for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
                    {
                        print '<div class="col-md-4">
                            <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=xx" style="margin:5px 5px;">$query[$i] <br>".($query2[$i])."</a>
                            </div>";
                    }

print '</div>';
```

How could I add the `<div class="row">` each 3 results? I'm just curious and want to learn.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the ".row" class the right way. What you want is something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

If you want them to be the same size as well, just use flexbox.

Something like this should work:

```
.row { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

Adding rows dynamically:

```
$lines = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',];
print '<div class="row">'; // let's start by printing the first one
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++) {
    // at every loop we check whether it's a multiple of three and end the current row and start another one.
    // we also need to check and avoid doing that if we're at the first or last element, to avoid empty divs
    // and similar situations.
    if ( 
           $i !== 0 
        && $i%3 === 0 
        && $i !== count($lines)-1 
    ) {
        print '</div><div class="row">';
    }
    print '
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="individ" href="index.php?p=xx" style="margin:5px 5px;">Line number' . $i . '</a>
        </div>
    ';
}
print '</div>'; // closing the last one
```

Comment: Thank you! Please read my edited comment and leave an reply if you have any idea of inserting a  div row each 3 results.

Answer (score -2):

I found solution. Problem appears, because some divs can't naturally float. If you can clear every third element, error dissapear.

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n + 1) {
clear: both;
```

}